# USB HD does not show up in dev/

Tags: gparted, usb-drive, fdisk, lsusb, parted

2TB USB drive does not show up at dev/ when I plug in. All other questions and answers seem to assume that the device is visible to these type of commands: lsblk, lshw, lsusb, parted, gparted, fdisk.

How do I troubleshoot when these tools do not show the device?

The power light is on and the disk is spinning up but it is as if the OS is ignoring the device.

Entry in var/log/syslog is:

```
Mar 27 15:54:19 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6696.569952] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Mar 27 15:54:19 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6696.586731] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab24
Mar 27 15:54:19 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6696.586740] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Mar 27 15:54:19 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6696.586745] usb 4-1: Product: BUP Slim RD
Mar 27 15:54:19 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6696.586750] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Seagate
Mar 27 15:54:19 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6696.586754] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: NA97A7D6
Mar 27 15:54:19 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6696.587605] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar 27 15:54:19 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6696.588341] scsi10 : usb-storage 4-1:1.0
Mar 27 15:54:19 r-ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 4, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-1"
Mar 27 15:54:19 r-ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 4, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Mar 27 15:54:20 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6697.586238] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  BUP Slim RD      0304 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Mar 27 15:54:20 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6697.586822] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Mar 27 15:54:20 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6697.587748] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
Mar 27 15:54:24 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6698.588799] ....ready
Mar 27 15:54:24 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6701.600122] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029167 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
Mar 27 15:55:00 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6737.397008] usb 4-1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Mar 27 15:55:05 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6742.394473] usb 4-1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Mar 27 15:55:10 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6747.763630] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for address device command
Mar 27 15:55:15 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6752.964863] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for address device command
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.168743] usb 4-1: device not accepting address 4, error -62
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.224834] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.224845] sd 10:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.224868] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.224872] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.224884] sd 10:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.224891] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.224894] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.225060] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] READ CAPACITY failed
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.225063] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc]  
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.225065] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.225067] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.225090] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.225093] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.225096] sdc: detected capacity change from 2000398933504 to 0
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.225177] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] READ CAPACITY failed
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.225180] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc]  
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.225181] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.225183] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.225204] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.225207] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.225209] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.227132] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88011818f600
Mar 27 15:55:16 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 6753.227136] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88011818f640
```

OK. Have taken the drive from the case and connected through a SATA to USB connector. Still does not show up. Output from syslog below:

```
Mar 27 16:26:00 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8597.027052] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
Mar 27 16:26:00 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8597.043387] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6254
Mar 27 16:26:00 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8597.043397] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Mar 27 16:26:00 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8597.043920] hub 3-2:1.0: USB hub found
Mar 27 16:26:00 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8597.044014] hub 3-2:1.0: 4 ports detected
Mar 27 16:26:01 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8597.330963] usb 3-2.4: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
Mar 27 16:26:01 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8597.349539] usb 3-2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6362
Mar 27 16:26:01 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8597.349553] usb 3-2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar 27 16:26:01 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8597.349561] usb 3-2.4: Product: Mass Storage Device
Mar 27 16:26:01 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8597.349568] usb 3-2.4: Manufacturer: Generic
Mar 27 16:26:01 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8597.349575] usb 3-2.4: SerialNumber: 058F312D81B
Mar 27 16:26:01 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8597.350348] usb-storage 3-2.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar 27 16:26:01 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8597.350508] scsi14 : usb-storage 3-2.4:1.0
Mar 27 16:26:01 r-ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 11: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.4"
Mar 27 16:26:01 r-ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 11 was not an MTP device
Mar 27 16:26:02 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8598.348459] scsi 14:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB SD Reader    1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Mar 27 16:26:02 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8598.349018] scsi 14:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Generic  USB CF Reader    1.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Mar 27 16:26:02 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8598.349575] scsi 14:0:0:2: Direct-Access     Generic  USB SM Reader    1.02 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Mar 27 16:26:02 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8598.350120] scsi 14:0:0:3: Direct-Access     Generic  USB MS Reader    1.03 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Mar 27 16:26:02 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8598.350744] sd 14:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Mar 27 16:26:02 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8598.351281] sd 14:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Mar 27 16:26:02 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8598.351634] sd 14:0:0:2: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
Mar 27 16:26:02 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8598.354646] sd 14:0:0:3: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
Mar 27 16:26:02 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8598.354933] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
Mar 27 16:26:02 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8598.357449] sd 14:0:0:1: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
Mar 27 16:26:02 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8598.358677] sd 14:0:0:2: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk
Mar 27 16:26:02 r-ubuntu kernel: [ 8598.359180] sd 14:0:0:3: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: I'd start by running `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in a terminal, and then plugging the device in

Comment: Thanks. Have edited the question to post the syslog entries. Any further comments? Is the drive broken? Can it be fixed?

Comment: The USB->SATA module in the enclosure is bad, an external power brick (if it uses one), or the drive itself is bad. Remove the drive from the enclosure and try to attach it directly to a SATA port on some computer and see if it works. Due to the nature of USB->SATA modules, you may have to reinitialize the drive to actually see if it works externally because sometimes they impose their own special formatting.

Comment: Thanks, steeldriver and heynnema. Have taken the drive from the case and connected via alternative SATA-USB setup. Still not showing up in dev/. Output from syslog above. Is it a lost cause? Can it be fixed?